# Reset a Swift Array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have arrays for truths and dares and I want to be able to reset the array once the "New Game" button is pressed.

Some background info on the arrays: The arrays are shuffled in the initializer and then every time a Dare or Truth button is pressed, it moves through the array and puts the prompt in a label.

I basically tried re-initializing the array in the swift file with the prompts but I can't connect the button to that file (maybe you can only do that in the View Controller? This is my first real project so I'm pretty unfamiliar with it).

I then tried re-initializing the prompts file in the view controller but I can't seem the reference it correctly.

```
import GameKit

struct PromptProvider {
    var truths = [
        "Truth A",
        "Truth B",
        "Truth C",
        "Truth D",
        "Truth E"]
    var dares = [
        "Dare A",
        "Dare B",
        "Dare C",
        "Dare D",
        "Dare E"]

    init() {
        self.enabledTruths = enabledTruths.shuffled()
        self.enabledDares = enabledDares.shuffled()
        }


    var truthIndex = 0
    mutating func randomTruth() -> String {
        if truthIndex == truths.count - 1 {
            return "You're out of truths. Click 'New Game' in the menu section." } else {
            truthIndex += 1
            return truths[truthIndex]
        }
    }
    var dareIndex = 0
    mutating func randomDare() -> String {
        if dareIndex == dares.count - 1 {
            return "You're out of dares. Click 'New Game' in the menu section." } else {
            dareIndex += 1
            return dares[dareIndex]
        }
    }
}
```

I basically just need to reset the array to start over at index 0 (and preferably also re-shuffle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your reinitializing code to a `mutating func` called `restart()`.  Call that from `init()`.  Also call it when you want to reset the `provider` by calling `provider.restart()`.

```
struct PromptProvider {

    var truthIndex = 0
    var dareIndex = 0

    var truths = [
        "Truth A",
        "Truth B",
        "Truth C",
        "Truth D",
        "Truth E"]

    var dares = [
        "Dare A",
        "Dare B",
        "Dare C",
        "Dare D",
        "Dare E"]

    init() {
        self.restart()
    }

    mutating func restart() {
        self.truths.shuffle()
        self.dares.shuffle()
        self.truthIndex = 0
        self.dareIndex = 0
    }

    mutating func randomTruth() -> String {
        if truthIndex == truths.count {
            return "You're out of truths. Click 'New Game' in the menu section."
        }
        else {
            defer { truthIndex += 1 }
            return truths[truthIndex]
        }
    }

    mutating func randomDare() -> String {
        if dareIndex == dares.count {
            return "You're out of dares. Click 'New Game' in the menu section."
        } else {
            defer { dareIndex += 1 }
            return dares[dareIndex]
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** To access all of the `truths` and `dares`, we increment the index after returning the value by using the `defer` statement.

---

**Example:**

```
var provider = PromptProvider()

for _ in 1...6 {
    print(provider.randomTruth())
    print(provider.randomDare())
}
```

> ```
> Truth D
> Dare C
> Truth E
> Dare A
> Truth C
> Dare B
> Truth A
> Dare E
> Truth B
> Dare D
> You're out of truths. Click 'New Game' in the menu section.
> You're out of dares. Click 'New Game' in the menu section.
> ```

```
provider.restart()

for _ in 1...6 {
    print(provider.randomTruth())
    print(provider.randomDare())
}
```

> ```
> Truth D
> Dare B
> Truth A
> Dare A
> Truth E
> Dare C
> Truth C
> Dare D
> Truth B
> Dare E
> You're out of truths. Click 'New Game' in the menu section.
> You're out of dares. Click 'New Game' in the menu section.
> ```